# How can I get 'Start' and 'End' from TimeSeries data using GroupBy.agg()?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to summarise a dataframe indexed by timeseries for a candlestick chart.  The dataframe has a sample every few seconds, which is not idea for displaying on a linechart for a longer time period.

I'd like to summarise by X minutes, with the values `[ min, mean, max, 'start', 'end' ]`

I can get the min, mean, max values OK, but how can I get the 'start' and 'end'?

The dataframe (df) may look like:

```
DateTime                Vals
2019-04-21 00:00:32     916892
2019-04-21 00:00:42     982588
2019-04-21 00:00:52     471452
2019-04-21 00:01:02     460576
2019-04-21 00:01:12     713764
2019-04-21 00:01:02     460576
...
2019-04-21 00:01:52     780545
2019-04-21 00:02:02     674151
...
2019-04-21 00:02:52     702329
2019-04-21 00:03:02     772237
...
2019-04-21 00:03:52     676713
2019-04-21 00:04:02     640359
...
2019-04-21 00:04:52     635224
2019-04-21 00:05:02     604004
....
```

(Data replaced with `...` to trim down)

So far I have this working:

```py
grp = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60s'))['Vals'].agg(['min', 'mean', 'max' ])
```

Which gives me the 'expected' output:

```
DateTime             min           mean     max
2019-04-21 00:00:00  471452  790310.666667  982588
2019-04-21 00:01:00  460576  705737.500000  780545
2019-04-21 00:02:00  674151  711281.333333  772771
2019-04-21 00:03:00  653066  774984.833333  854880
2019-04-21 00:04:00  635224  655078.333333  676513
```

However I'd also like:

```
DateTime             min           mean     max     start   end
2019-04-21 00:00:00  471452  790310.666667  982588  916892  471452
2019-04-21 00:01:00  460576  705737.500000  780545  460576  780545
2019-04-21 00:02:00  674151  711281.333333  772771  674151  702329
2019-04-21 00:03:00  653066  774984.833333  854880  640359  676713
2019-04-21 00:04:00  635224  655078.333333  676513  640359  635224
```

Is there a convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify additional aggfuncs `"first"` for "start" and `"last"` for "end":

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60s'))['Vals'].agg(
    ['min', 'mean', 'max', 'first', 'last'])
                        min           mean     max   first    last
DateTime                                                          
2019-04-21 00:00:00  471452  790310.666667  982588  916892  471452
2019-04-21 00:01:00  460576  603865.250000  780545  460576  780545
2019-04-21 00:02:00  674151  688240.000000  702329  674151  702329
2019-04-21 00:03:00  676713  724475.000000  772237  772237  676713
2019-04-21 00:04:00  635224  637791.500000  640359  640359  635224
2019-04-21 00:05:00  604004  604004.000000  604004  604004  604004
```

If you want to rename the output columns, specify tuples of the format <(desired_name, aggfunc)>:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60s'))['Vals'].agg(
     ['min', 'mean', 'max', ('start', 'first'), ('end', 'last')])

                        min           mean     max   start     end
DateTime                                                          
2019-04-21 00:00:00  471452  790310.666667  982588  916892  471452
2019-04-21 00:01:00  460576  603865.250000  780545  460576  780545
2019-04-21 00:02:00  674151  688240.000000  702329  674151  702329
2019-04-21 00:03:00  676713  724475.000000  772237  772237  676713
2019-04-21 00:04:00  635224  637791.500000  640359  640359  635224
2019-04-21 00:05:00  604004  604004.000000  604004  604004  604004
```

Comment: Thankyou!  I have no idea how I didnt think of that.  I tried everything not-obviously... obviously.

Are these aggfuncs defined anywhere handy?  I had thought I dragged myself through the documentation relating to agg pretty well, but obviously not.  

Thanks again!

Comment: @DaveL You will find a description of all the commonly used aggregation functions here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation